# Bash Interpreter read

Tags: bash, interpreter, git-bash

```
#!/bin/bash
read k
read m
read fileName
head -n -$k $fileName | tail -n +$m $fileName
```

Hi, this is what I have now. I have to create bash interpreter that removes the lines from head and removes lines from tail in text file.

I have to excute this bash interpreter by this way.
./strip.sh 2 3 hi.txt > bye.txt

How do I read 2 for k and 3 for m? 
Also how do I read hi.txt for fileName?
Also is my code correct?
Please answer these question. I am really new to this bash interpreter.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is for reading values from standard input. What you want are positional parameters:

```
k=$1
m=$2
fileName=$3 
head -n -$k "$fileName" | tail -n +$m
```

Drop the final argument of `fileName` from `tail`, because it will read from standard input (fed by the standard output of `head`), not a named file.

Comment: I have another question when I excute it, sometimes it only removes less than what it should remove. like ./strip.sh 4 5 hi.txt > bye.txt should remove first 4 lines and last 5 lines, but it only removes first 4 lines and last "4" lines. Also, when I excute ./strip.sh 1 1 hi.txt > bye.txt, it only removes last line, not first line....

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner point you in the correct direction but the script as is at the moment does not work as you expected. If you want to try another approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

k=${1}
file=${3}
lines=$(wc -l < "${file}")
m=$[${lines}-${2}]

awk 'NR>'${k}' && NR<='${m} "${file}"
```

Where:

- `set -u`: make undefined variables (such as missing params) stop the execution
- `$(wc -l < "${file}")`: count the total lines of the file.
- `$[${lines}-${2}]`: subtract from bottom lines desired (passed to remove from the total number of lines
- `awk 'NR>k && NR<=m'`: print (default awk behaviour) the lines > k and <= m

Comment: Reading the file twice to obtain its length is an antipattern. It is sometimes useful, but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @tripleee: you're right in general but to *remove the last x lines*, if a generic tool is processing a file **line by line** how can it know when to stop? It is aware of EOF only when it actually reaches the end. So you need the possibility to program it to go back x lines from the end (it's possible with sed or awk complicating the script) or you have to know *before* start in which line you have to stop.